# Differences between MySQL and Oracle databases

Tags: mysql, oracle, rdbms

What are the differences between MySQL and Oracle databases. I know both are RDBMS, both use SQL as Query language and both are developed by Oracle. So what are the differences between these two technically?

Comment: Why don't you search for the same on Google?

Comment: Your question is too broad, but Oracle is an enterprise database supporting many things which MySQL does not, including analytic functions, function indices, etc.

Comment: Ha ha ...!! If any thing can Google tell me. why do we use stack Overflow

Comment: looks like an assignment for a subject...

Comment: All RDBMS systems use SQL. Oracle owns other database products too, such as BDB. Off topic.

Comment: Google does not answer you everything, but this question is easily be answered by googling your title "Differences between MySQL and Oracle databases"

Comment: @RavinduShantha if you want to ask that kind of ethic question, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ will be suitable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used Oracle in Deuth Bank for 1,5 years, and some experience with MySQL on other job.
In general, Oracle is much more powerful and is a deeper RDBMS, which allows you to write any complex system. That's why it is used in banking, military, and science fields.

MySQL - is light, simple RDBMS, it is very well for web, for example small internet shop, your personal web page, or page of a school. More complex web often use RDBMS PostgreSQL.

Oracle allows you to use packages (often on PL/SQL), coursurs (same as subselect), PL/SQL language, Roles, snapshot, synonym, tablespace.
Also Oracle has more advanced data types, and a bit different datatypes.

For example:
`BIGINT` (8 Bytes) In MySQL, in Oracle called - `NUMBER` (19,0).

For what I miss in Oracle is `select * from dual`, wherein **dual** is a default virtual table in Oracle. 
For more deep comparison, please check compare table on Oracle's website:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12155/oracle_mysql_compared.htm#i1027526

Answer (score -1):

Mysql and Oracle are both RDMS. oracle not develop MySQL he purchase it.
Both are same just syntax diffrence like
for limit rows in mysql

```
select * from tbl limit 1
```

in oracle

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ROWNUM <=1;
```

mysql is open source and oracle is paid.for more diffrence in query you can see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12155/oracle_mysql_compared.htm#CHDIIBJH)

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels...